# Collection of unique items with custom comparator

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, collections, compare

I need collection, similar to std::set, so every element can be inserted only once, but I need to provide my custom comparator to decide whether elements are equal.
How can I do that in C#?
Seems C# doesn't have set at all?

Answer (score 3):

.NET comes with an unordered set type called [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1), multiple constructors of which accept a user-supplied [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) instance:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

set.Add("abc"); // the statement returns `true`
set.Add("def"); // the statement returns `true`
set.Add("abc"); // returns `false`, abc already exists in set

set.Contains("abc"); // returns `true` as expected
set.Contains("ABC"); // also `true`, thanks to our case-insensitive comparer
```

Comment: But with custom IEqualityComparer Contains function seems to call GetHashCode function and compare elements hashes, not Equals one, that accepts two items as a parameter..

Comment: @Random hashset uses `GetHashCode` first and then `Equals`.

Comment: @GuruStron Contains uses only GetHashCode, and compare hashcodesm not the elements themselves,  it's what I see in debugger

Comment: @Random That's the case regardless of whether you supply a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` or not - `GetHashCode()` is necessary for resolving target buckets in the underlying hashtable-like storage of the set - `Equals` is then used to resolve collisions. [See source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs#L267-L272)

Comment: @Random then you need to check your custom comparer and/or debug data, cause `Equals` is clearly [used](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashSet.cs,1159). Though for obvious reasons it will be only used only if hashcodes match.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's why I can't use his - I can't get same hashcode for my elements, I need only custom comparator for the elements, without hashes

Comment: @GuruStron yep, I wasn't clear, and it wasn't clear to me yet - my problem here that I can't get same hashcode for elements that I want to consider to be the same

Comment: @Random Can you meaningfully implement ordinal/3-way comparisons (`a > b`) for the target type? If so, [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) might be a better fit - it's essentially an ordered set implemented using a heap - it's `Contains` implementation relies solely on 3-way comparison

Comment: @Random Why can't you get a hash code, even though you can determine equality? Can you give more details about what exactly you're working with?

Answer (score 2):

The object you are looking for is `HashSet<T>`, which will only add items once.

If you want to implement your own equality comparisons, you can have the class implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and provide the logic for equality there.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-6.0) which has [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-sortedset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) accepting [custom `IComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=net-6.0) and does not allow duplicate items:

> A SortedSet object maintains a sorted order without affecting performance as elements are inserted and deleted. **Duplicate elements are not allowed**. Changing the sort values of existing items is not supported and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Or [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0) with [custom comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-sorteddictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) for keys.